# Demoworkbench in CORDA is not working

Tags: blockchain, corda

[image: Error Image]

I have attached the error log. please clarify what is the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The port that the node wants to connect to is already being used by another process. You need to kill the process using this port (possibly another instance of Corda) and restart demobench.